# Does $\langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi, u\rangle = \langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-i\tau\psi}), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle$?

Tags: proof-explanation, inner-products, fourier-transform

In the proof of proposition 1.3.2 in the book on Fourier Integral Operators by Duistermaat, it is claimed that $\langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi, u\rangle = \langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-i\tau\psi}), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle$. Here $\psi \in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^p)$, and $\varphi \in C^\infty_0(U_0)$ for some neighborhood $U_0$. They technically also define a function $\varphi'$ which is equal to 1 on the support of $\varphi$ and then claim
$$\langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi, u\rangle = \langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-i\tau\psi}\varphi'), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle,$$ but I believe this should not be relevant to this first step. They use the standard inner product

$$\langle f, g\rangle = \int f(x)g(x)\text{d}x$$

with real functions.

It seems to me that the given statement cannot be true because
\begin{align}
\langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi, u\rangle &= \langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi'\varphi, u\rangle \\
&= \langle e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi', \varphi u\rangle \\
&= \langle \mathcal{F}(e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi'), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle \\
&= \langle \mathcal{P}\circ \mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-i\tau \psi}\varphi'), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle \\
&\neq \langle\mathcal{F}^{-1}(e^{-i\tau\psi}\varphi'), \mathcal{F}(\varphi u)\rangle.
\end{align}

Unfortunately, if I continue their derivation with my altnerative equality I cannot proof the proposition. Does anyone know where I went wrong?

Comment: It's unclear as to the definitions of $\tau$ and $\psi$.  Are they real numbers?  Are they operators?  For example, is $\mathscr{F^{-1}}\{f\}(\psi)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\tau)e^{i\psi \tau}\,d\tau$ for $f\in L^1$?  If so, then here the Fourier transform should be considered as a tempered distribution on the Schwartz space of functions.

Comment: It is not the real scalar product, the functions are complex